# .IsKeyDown(Keys keys) not Working?

Tags: c#, xna

I am new to C# (transferring from the Web Development world).

Anyway, I am making a simple background color changing program that takes input from the user. I have three color variables  (which I pass into this: `backgroundColor = new Color(redIntensity, greenIntensity, blueIntensity);`)

So then in the `Update()` method I have this:

```
        //[colorIntensity] = 0 then count up...when pressed
        //Changes background color
        KeyboardState keyState = new KeyboardState();

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.R))
        {
            redIntensity++;
        }
```

The above code doesn't work! However, if I change the:

```
        if(keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.R)) ...
```

To:

```
       if(keyState.IsKeyUp(Keys.R)) ...
```

It works fine...

So, any advice?

EDIT: I'm using XNA Framework.

Comment: What technology are you using? WPF? WinForms? And what triggers the `Update()` method? Typically in a key up/down/press event handler you'll get an argument that contains the code for the key that was pressed to trigger the event. Use that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll edit it in as well. 

I am using the XNA framework. It auto generates the Update() method, along with others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating an empty `KeyboardState` structure, so it will always show all keys as up.

Use the `Keyboard.GetState` method to get the current state:

```
KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
```